# How to make mysql query execution slow only by configuration

Tags: mysql, linux

I want to make the query execution speed slow in mysql. Not by not indexing and writing bad queries.

Only by configuration, I want the query execution to become slow.

I tried changing the below values in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 0M
max_allowed_packet      = 1M
thread_stack            = 19K
thread_cache_size       = 2

##disabled cache
query_cache_limit       = 0
query_cache_size        = 0
##limited innoDB buffer pool size
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 0M
```

Still there is no significant reduction in the query execution time.

> SQl  version: 5.5.57-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Any help or suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: Define slow. Slower than a snail?

Comment: yes.sort of. I want to make them slower by configuration change and also make them faster by changing same parameter/s

Comment: I don't think there is a configuration parameter, that makes single simple query slower than a snail. All the cache parameters probably have the effect you desire, but only when there is some load on the server. If you want to make queries uniformly slower, then you need to modify the source code of the MySQL server or the client.

Comment: Thanks @ErkiA . By load you mean the no.of connections?? or the amount of result from the query??

Comment: Maybe running mysql in docker container and play with `docker run` options to limit cpu and memory for it can do the trick.